# Unchecking the checkbox dynamically

Tags: jquery-mobile, checkbox

Intending to empty the value of Checkbox , if any , on Button click.

Tried all given solutions , but no change (Its retaining its checked state):

```
1-- $("#checkbox-1").attr("checked",false);
2-- $('#checkbox-1').attr('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
3-- $("#checkbox-1").prop("checked",false);
4-- $('#checkbox-1').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');
```

Kindly help , if i am going wrong anywhere !

Comment: please add the jquery version and also check whether the function reaches the onclick method. And try adding this function in document ready which binds it on page loads.

Comment: Jquery-1.10.2 , Jquery.mobile-1.4.0

Comment: I tried checking it dynamically , in document.ready But that is also not working !

Comment: is it like  on clicking a button, the checkbox toggles or simply always you want the checkbox to get unchecked ?

Comment: On Click Always i want it to be unchecked , be it filled or not !

Comment: First of all try to find out whether your button's onclick is getting called or not.

Comment: please look into the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/GaBHC/2/ , I hope there is some problem with your IDs

Comment: Yeah , button click is executed ! Rest all functionality is executed in button Click ! @Pramod

Comment: @Kannan_SJD , i rechecked my ids and replaced with a new one to test !  But the same problem persists, for me !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fH8mE/ , this should work right ?

Comment: It is working, but you forgot to load jquery library... check http://jsfiddle.net/fH8mE/1/

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>   I have included these libraries in my code ! Not well versed with JS Fiddle !

Comment: what do you mean _empty the value of Checkbox_? uncheck it?

Comment: Yeah I meant , since it was checked , I was intending to uncheck it on button Click. @Omar

Comment: this `$('#checkbox-1').prop('checked', true).checkboxradio('refresh');` should work. Make sure you wrap `click` listener in `pagecreate` event.